# Ad Banner appears under toolbar on certain ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, ads, adbannerview

On certain viewcontrollers, my ad banner will appear above my tooldbar (which I want). However, on other viewcontrollers, it appears under the toolbar; hidden. All the code is the same for the different swift files. How do I go about putting the ad banner above the toolbar? Pics included:

What I want:
[image: Working]
What I don't want:
[image: Not Working]

----Working ad code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds


    class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

        var bannerView: GADBannerView!

        override func viewDidLoad(){
            super.viewDidLoad()


            //---------ADS----------------
            // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
            bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

            addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
        }
        func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
            bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(bannerView)
            view.addConstraints(
                [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                    toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                    attribute: .top,
                                    multiplier: 1,
                                    constant: 1),
                 NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                    attribute: .centerX,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                    toItem: view,
                                    attribute: .centerX,
                                    multiplier: 1,
                                    constant: 1)
                ])


            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-9944401739416572/3708634126"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        }
        // Forces Portrait
        override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
            return false
        }

        override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
        //End of Forces Portrait */
```

Not Working Code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

///You are using this class a UIViewCOntroller in storyBoard bbut hadnt provided **tablelist: UIViewController**
///This is Necessary in case when you are going to assign it to a UIVIewController
class toollist: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = \[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red\]



        ///You need to Sert datasource and Delegate as its not a TableViewController its just a Normal TableView
        self.animalTableView.dataSource = self
        self.animalTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


        //---------ADS-------------------------------------------
        // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    }


    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            \[NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 1),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 1)
            \])


        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-9944401739416572/3708634126"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }




    //--------------------------LIST Specs-------------------------------------------------------//


    let tool = \["APGAR Calculator","Dopamine Calculator","GCS Calculator","Parkland Burn Formula","Rule of Nines (Adult)","Epocrates","Event Logger","Rate Calculator","Medical Sign Language"/*"EKG Examples"*/\]


    ///You did not connected a outlet of tableView
    ///as its not a tableViewController just a TableView so it should be Connected



    @IBOutlet weak var animalTableView: UITableView!


    ///Set elements in cell
    func tableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listoftools"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tool\[indexPath.row\]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.animalTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }

   // var AMPT : \[UIImage\] = \[
       // UIImage(named: "AMPT")! \]

    var sign : \[UIImage\] = \[
        UIImage(named: "signlang1")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang2")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang3")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang4")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang5")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang6")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang7")!,
        UIImage(named: "signlang8")!,
        \]



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return tool.count
    }


    //--------------------------Respiratory List--------------------



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let Tools = UIStoryboard(name: "Tools", bundle: nil)
        let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController
        let apgarcalc = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "apgarcalculator") as! DopamineCalculator
        let dopecalc = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dopaminecalculator") as! DopamineCalculator
        let gcscalc = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gcscalculator") as! DopamineCalculator
        let ruleofninecalc = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "adultruleofnines") as! DopamineCalculator
        let burncalc = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "burnpercentcalculator") as! DopamineCalculator
        let evenlog = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OPENTIME") as! eventLogger
        let tempo = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "taptempo") as! taptempo
     //   let ekg = Tools.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ekglist") as! ekglist
        // let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController

        switch indexPath.row
        {

             case 0:
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(apgarcalc, animated: true)
             break;
             case 1:

             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dopecalc, animated: true)
             break;
             case 2:
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcscalc, animated: true)
             break;
             case 3:
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(burncalc, animated: true)
             break;
             case 4:
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ruleofninecalc, animated: true)
             break;
             case 5:
            //epocrates
             if let url = URL(string: "http://www.epocrates.com") { UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)}
             break;
        case 6:
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(evenlog, animated: true)
            break;
        case 7:

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tempo, animated: true)
            break;
        case 8:
            Vc.passedArray = sign
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;





        default:
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(evenlog, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you state certain view controllers do you mean different simulator sizes?

Comment: All the view controllers are the same size

Comment: Any ideas on what could be causing it?